# ¿Se pueden crear combinaciones en grupos de N número de caracteres sin anidar varios for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me encuentro realizando una aplicación en JavaScript (con jQuery), en la cual el funcionamiento principal es crear combinaciones únicas y agrupadas en cierto numero. Pero la manera en la que las realizo no parece ser la mejor forma.

Ejemplo:

```js
var cadena = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]; //Caracteres que va a combinar
var arrayCombinaciones = []; //Almacena las combinaciones
var grupo = 3; //le indico la cantidad de cuantos caracteres quiero que sean las combinaciones.
var posicion = 0;

switch (grupo) {

  case 2:
    for (var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < cadena.length; j++) {
        if (cadena[i] != cadena[j]) {

          arrayCombinaciones[posicion++] = [cadena[i], cadena[j]];
        }
      }
    }
    break;

  case 3:
    for (var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < cadena.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < cadena.length; k++) {
          if (cadena[i] != cadena[j] && cadena[i] != cadena[k] && cadena[j] != cadena[k]) {

            arrayCombinaciones[posicion++] = [cadena[i], cadena[j], cadena[k]];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    break;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayCombinaciones));
```

Y en caso de que el grupo sea de dos, necesito hacer dos `for` y con un `if` validar que los caracteres no sean iguales e ir almacenando las combinaciones en el "arrayCombinaciones". En este caso el resultado de agruparlos de 2, sería:

> [["1","2"],["1","3"],["1","4"],["1","5"],["1","6"],["1","7"],["1","8"],["2","1"],["2","3"],["2","4"],["2","5"],["2","6"],["2","7"],["2","8"],["3","1"],["3","2"],["3","4"],["3","5"],["3","6"],["3","7"],["3","8"],["4","1"],["4","2"],["4","3"],["4","5"],["4","6"],["4","7"],["4","8"],["5","1"],["5","2"],["5","3"],["5","4"],["5","6"],["5","7"],["5","8"],["6","1"],["6","2"],["6","3"],["6","4"],["6","5"],["6","7"],["6","8"],["7","1"],["7","2"],["7","3"],["7","4"],["7","5"],["7","6"],["7","8"],["8","1"],["8","2"],["8","3"],["8","4"],["8","5"],["8","6"],["8","7"]]

¿Y si por ejemplo quiero grupos de 10? Debo de hacer 10 for anidados, pero no me parece que sea la mejor manera, no sé si exista otra forma de evitar hacer tantos `for` de acuerdo al número de grupo indicado. En pocas palabras, que sea dinámico.

Comment: Dependiendo de los recursos que tengas, podrías plantearte recursividad o cambiar a un número específico de bucles `while` en lugar de N bucles `for`. Ahora no puedo mirar esto, pero cuando salga del trabajo le echo un ojo si no has encontrado solución.

Comment: No, aún no consigo una solución @AlvaroMontoro , pero me sería de mucha utilidad su aporte.

Comment: Te acaban de dar una respuesta que de ve bien. Me parece que ya no me vas a necesitar :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una forma de implementarlo de forma recursiva:

```js
function comb(alfabeto, n, resultados, resultado) {
    if(!resultado) {
        resultado = [];
    }
    for(var i=0; i<alfabeto.length; ++i) {
        var newResultado = resultado.slice();
        var newAlfabeto = alfabeto.slice();
        newResultado.push(alfabeto[i]);
        newAlfabeto.splice(i, 1);
        if(n>1) {
            comb(newAlfabeto, n-1, resultados, newResultado);
        } else {
            resultados.push(newResultado);
        }
    }
}

var cadena = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];//Caracteres que va a combinar
var arrayCombinaciones = [];//Almacena las combinaciones
var grupo = 3;//le indico la cantidad de cuantos caracteres quiero que sean las combinaciones.

comb(cadena, grupo, arrayCombinaciones);    
       
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayCombinaciones));
```

Basicamente, la funcion itera el alfabeto completo y crea tantos arreglos como caracteres en el alfabeto.
Al volver a invocarse a si misma, lo hace con un nuevo alfabeto con el caracter utilizado removido y un arreglo resultado incompleto.

Cuando ya utilizo la cantidad de caracteres `n` completa el arreglo final de resultados.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Klaimmore , era exactamente lo que quería, nunca me lo hubiera imaginado de esa forma. Aunque no me quedó del todo claro la explicación del código.

Comment: Tal vez podrias visualizar su ejecucion con la ayuda de http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit al menos para grupo=2 podras ver paso a paso lo que ocurre.

Answer (score 3):

Edicion: reemplazo mi respuesta anterior por esta que regresa resultados con grupos de N integrantes.

```
function permutaciones(arr,cont){

    if(cont  < 1 || cont == undefined){
        cont = 1;
    }

    if(cont == 1){
        return permutarArray(arr,arr);
    }

    return permutarArray(arr,permutaciones(arr,cont-1));
}

function permutarArray(a1,a2){

    var result = [];

    a1.forEach( e1 =>{

        var map2 = a2.map( e2 =>{
                        if(Array.isArray(e2)){
                            return [e1].concat(e2);
                        }else{
                            return [e1,e2]; 
                        }
                    });

        result = result.concat(map2);
    });

    return result;
}

var cadena = [1,2];

console.log(permutaciones(cadena,2));
```

Añado otra version sin usar ni foreach ni map:

```
//Funcion de alto nivel para permutaciones
//arr: array a permutar
//cont: contador de permutaciones a realizar
function permutaciones(arr,cont){

    //Por defecto se realiza una vez
    if(cont  < 1 || cont == undefined){
        cont = 1;
    }

    if(cont == 1){
        //Caso base, se permuta el array con sigo mismo
        return permutacionesIndices(arr,0,arr,0);
    }

    //Se permuta el array con la siguiente iteracion
    return permutacionesIndices(arr,0,permutaciones(arr,cont-1),0);
}

//Funcion de bajo nivel para permutaciones
//a1: primer arreglo a permutar
//i1: indice del elemento que se agregara al arreglo resultado
//a2: segunda arreglo a permutar
//i2: indice del elemento que se agregara al arreglo resultado

function permutacionesIndices(a1,i1,a2,i2){

    //Potencial elemento a agregar
    var elemento;
    if(Array.isArray(a2[i2])){
        //Compuesto un array que tenga al primer elemento y a los elementos del segundo si este es un array
        elemento = [a1[i1]].concat(a2[i2]);
    }
    else{
        //Compuesto por los elementos de ambos arreglos si son ambos numeros
        elemento = [a1[i1],a2[i2]];
    }


    //i1Sig: valor de i1 para la siguiente iteracion
    //toma i1+1, si alcanza al final del array vuelve a 0
    var i1Sig = (i1 + 1 == a1.length ? 0: i1 + 1);

    //i2Sig: valor de i2 para la siguiente iteracion
    //mantiene su valor, a menos que i1Sig haya terminado de iterar por todo a1 (cunado vale 0)
    var i2Sig = (i1Sig == 0 ? i2+1: i2);

    //Cuando se recorrio todo el a2 significa que ya se itero por cada par de elementos posibles en las permutaciones
    if(i2Sig == a2.length){
        //Caso base, se parte de un resultado vacio
        return [];
    }

    //Se devuelve el elemento actual, encadenado a la siguiente iteracion
    return [elemento].concat(permutacionesIndices(a1,i1Sig,a2,i2Sig));
}

var cadena = [1,2];//[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var p = permutaciones(cadena,2);

console.log(p);
```

Comment: Muy buen aporte @Sacha , pero dónde elijo para hacerlo por grupos. hice la prueba con el map, pero me hace combinaciones de 2 solamente.

Comment: Se ve bien, como adaptarias esta solución para todo `n`?

Comment: Oh, cuando lei n grupos entendi que la cantidad de grupos era N, no que los grupos contengan N elementos cada uno, eliminare mi respuesta y la re-respondere bien contestada

Comment: @Klaimmore ahi esta si la version generalizada, les pido por favor mil disculpas por haber malinterpretado el enunciado.